# Acentuações PostgreSQL | EntityFramework | NpgsqlTsVector

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

Estou escrevendo um método de consulta ao banco de dados e tenho 2 desafios:

1º Pesquisa full-text (Ex: "MOUSE WIRELESS AZUL" ser encontrado ao digitar "MOUSE AZUL")

- Este problema foi resolvido com o NpgsqlTsVector do Postgre, foi criado um atributo na classe e o mesmo é mapeado para o banco criando uma coluna de "Matches" e gerenciando o índice responsável

2º Pesquisar ignorando acentuações (Ex: Ao pesquisar "JOSE", retornar "JOSE e JOSÉ)

- Eu até consigo resolver esse problema utilizando a extensão Unaccent do Postgre, o problema é que ela aparentemente não em conjunto com o NpgsqlTsVector.

```
queryable = queryable .Where(x => x.Pesquisa.Matches(fitro));
                queryable = queryable.Where(x => x.DescricaoSaida.Contains(EF.Functions.Unaccent(fitro)));

queryable = queryable .Where(x => x.Pesquisa.Matches(fitro));
```

Alguém já passou por essa situação e pode me dar alguma orientação?

Comment: Veja se o ajuda: [Class NpgsqlFullTextSearchDbFunctionsExtensions.Unaccent()](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/api/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.NpgsqlFullTextSearchDbFunctionsExtensions.html#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_NpgsqlFullTextSearchDbFunctionsExtensions_Unaccent_DbFunctions_System_String_System_String_)

Answer (score -3):

Se escrever a query de forma específica for uma opção dá pra fazer da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT * FROM pessoa p
WHERE UPPER(TRANSLATE(p.name, 
                      'áéíóúâêîôûãõàèìòùäëïöüçÁÉÍÓÚÂÊÎÔÛÃÕÀÈÌÒÙÄËÏÖÜÇ', 
                      'aeiouaeiouaoaeioucAEIOUAEIOUAOAEIOUC')) 
LIKE UPPER('%jose%');
```

É uma alternativa não muito bonita, mas funciona. Se você conseguir prever os caracteres que vai precisar dá pra reduzir o tamanho do translate também. Criei algumas extensões no C# para fazer isso por mim na época que precisei.

Se precisar de mais alguns exemplos posso ir te ajudando por aqui.